# Jinja using a variable as the name of the file used in a Jinja "include"

Tags: include, jinja2

Within jinja I am trying to pass a variable into the file name used by the "include" for example: {% include = variable1 %}

Something like this:

```
{% set filepath = ['Templates/file1.j2', 'Templates/file2.j2', 'Templetes/file3.j2'] %}
These are the files:
{% for list in filepath -%}
   '{{ list }}'
{% endfor %} 

{% set Mypath = filepath[1] %}
This is the path and file to use: '{{ Mypath }}'

{% include "'" Mypath "'" %}
```

The result I am hoping to achieve should look like this.

```
{% include = 'Templates/file2.j2' %}.
```

Is is possible to pass a variable into an include in this fashion within Jinja?